how to delete range of keyframe (tracking data) from a tracker?
I'm doing camera tracking. In this case the pattern to be tracked is obscured midway because it's being covered by other object for couple of frames so on that area the tracker is off , but it goes back on track again as the covering object is gone. There is range of keyframe in the middle of duration which is invalid and I want to delete it.
How can I delete the range of keyframe from the tracker ? seems only possible to delete tracking data from current frame either forward or backward (shift T or alt T).
Normally if the pattern is obscured I used 2 markers/trackers and then join them.
But I want to know if possible to remove the range of tracking data in the middle ?
